# Why is the Great Dark Spot so shortliving unlike the Great Red Spot?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, solar-system, observational-astronomy

[The Great Dark Spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Dark_Spot) is an anti-cyclone in Neptune. But unlike the Great Red Spot of Jupiter which lasts for more than hundred years, the Great Dark Spot exists for only one year or so. Why is it so??

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46883

Comment: @hwlau: +1 to that answer. It was intuitive. But I think I have asked wrong quo & so couldn't get any answer.

Comment: I don't think anyone really know the answer, or have the knowledge to guess an answer. You may get try http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/